# Clicar num link e imprimir a página de destino assim que ela abrir

Tags: javascript

Estou usando `self.print()` para chamar impressão e com isso abre a opção de imprimir a página que estou. Porém, gostaria que antes de chamar a impressão pudesse ir para uma outra página através do a `href`... Tudo isso ao clicar na palavrar "*Imprimir*".
Isso é possível?

O meu HTML

```
<tr>
    <td width="60"><a id="meulink" href="index.php?content=fones-uteis&action=update&id=<?=$uteis['id'];?>">Imprimir</a></td>
    <td width="60"><a href="index.php?content=fones-uteis&action=update&id=<?=$uteis['id'];?>">Editar</a></td>
    <td width="60"><a href="index.php?content=fones-uteis&action=delete&id=<?=$uteis['id'];?>" onclick="return confirmDelete();">Excluir</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Se mudas de página o script pára de executar e o `self.print()` não vai ser corrido.

Comment: E qual das duas páginas você quer imprimir?

Comment: A página que "aparecerá" após o clique em "Imprimir".

Comment: Essa palavra imprimir está em que tipo de elemento? `<button>`, `<a>` ou outro?

Comment: Está em um elemento <a>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando clicar em "Imprimir" chame uma função que redireciona para outra página, na outra página no load, chame a função de imprimir.

Na página onde tem o link com o texto "Imprimir" faça isso:

JavaScript

```
$('#id_imprimir').click(function(){   
   window.open('url da sua página aqui', '_blank');
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="id_imprimir">Imprimir</a>
```

Na outra página faça isso:

```
$(function(){
  window.print();
});
```

Não rolou aqui o teste que fiz usando o location.href, não abria em nova aba, por isso mudei.
Não sei como esta sua estrutura JS, esse exemplo está simples, apenas para você entender como vai funcionar. Dessa forma ao cair na outra página automaticamente vai ser aberto a janela de impressão. Ai com css "media print" você configura o que vai ser impresso e tal.

Comment: Do modo como foi perguntado parece justamente que a duvida acontece pois ela não poderia mexer (acrescentar código) na página destino que seria impressa. Mas já que foi marcada como resposta correta... apenas lembrando que com esse `window.print` a pagina será impressa sempre que for acessada, independente se veio do botão imprimir ou não.

Answer (score 3):

Podes testar assim:

```
var el = document.querySelector('a#meulink');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      // impedir que o link seja seguido imediatamente
    var href = this.href;    // colocar em cache o url
    self.print();            // imprimir
    window.location.href = href;  // ir para nova página
});
```

Curiosamente não consigo simular isto no jsFiddle ou jsBin. Mas fiz uma página localmente e funcionou bem.

Comment: Tentei esse função e me cheuei a um loop infinito.
Agora coloquei meu código na pergunta.

Comment: @FernandaFerreira em que browser?

Comment: Estou usando o Chrome.

Comment: Eu tb, v42, funcionou para mim. Vou investigar mais...

Comment: O código que usei está correto?

Comment: @FernandaFerreira tem um erro que eu corrigí na minha resposta. Uma virgula aqui `this,href;` que deve ser um ponto. Já agora não mudes a pergunta, senão as respostas vão ficando erradas...

Comment: @FernandaFerreira testaste de novo com a versão sem erro que tenho na resposta?

Comment: Testei, deu loop de novo.